# Scrape Table HTML with beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website which has been built with tables. Here a link of a page's example: http://www.rc2.vd.ch/registres/hrcintapp-pub/companyReport.action?rcentId=5947621600000055031025&lang=FR&showHeader=false

My goal is to get the name and the last name : Lass Christian (screenshot below).

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3nMb.png

I've already scraped many websites but this one I have absolutly no idea how to proceed. There are only 'tables' without any ID/Class tags and I can't figure out where I'm  supposed to start.

Here's an exemple of the HTML code :

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tbody><tr bgcolor="#f0eef2">
                
                <th colspan="3">Associés, gérants et personnes ayant qualité pour signer</th>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#f0eef2">
                
                <th>
                    <a class="hoverable" onclick="document.forms[0].rcentId.value='5947621600000055031025';document.forms[0].lang.value='FR';document.forms[0].searchLang.value='FR';document.forms[0].order.value='N';document.forms[0].rad.value='N';document.forms[0].goToAdm.value='true';document.forms[0].showHeader.value=false;document.forms[0].submit();event.returnValue=false; return false;">
                        Nom et Prénoms, Origine, Domicile, Part sociale
                    </a>
                    
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a class="hoverable" onclick="document.forms[0].rcentId.value='5947621600000055031025';document.forms[0].lang.value='FR';document.forms[0].searchLang.value='FR';document.forms[0].order.value='F';document.forms[0].rad.value='N';document.forms[0].goToAdm.value='true';document.forms[0].showHeader.value=false;document.forms[0].submit();event.returnValue=false; return false;">
                        Fonctions
                    </a>
                    
                        <img src="/registres/hrcintapp-pub/img/down_r.png" align="bottom" border="0" alt="">
                    
                </th>
                <th>Mode Signature</th>
            </tr>
            
                <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    
                    
                    <td>
                        <span style="text-decoration: none;">
                            Lass Christian, du Danemark, à Yverdon-les-Bains, avec 200 parts de CHF 100
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><span style="text-decoration: none;">associé gérant </span>&nbsp;</td>
                    
                    
                        <td><span style="text-decoration: none;">signature individuelle</span>&nbsp;</td>                   
                    
                    
                </tr>
            
            
            
            
        </tbody></table>
```

Comment: You only want the single row that has the name?

Comment: Yes I'd like to get *Lass Christian*, but not all the pages on the website are the same, sometimes there are more tables. So I want to find out a way to get the name for all kind of page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get the name from the page, the table is right after the anchor with the *id* *adm*, once you have that you have numerous ways to get what you need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.rc2.vd.ch/registres/hrcintapp-pub/companyReport.action?rcentId=5947621600000055031025&lang=FR&showHeader=false')


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
table  = soup.select_one("#adm").find_next("table")
name = table.select_one("td span[style^=text-decoration:]").text.split(",", 1)[0].strip()
print(name)
```

Output:

```
Lass Christian
```

Or:

```
table = soup.select_one("#adm").find_next("table")
name = table.find("tr",bgcolor="#ffffff").td.span.text.split(",", 1)[0].strip()
```

Comment: Appreciate the nice answer ... increased my learning as well!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
results = soup.find_all("tr", {"bgcolor" : "#ffffff"})
for result in results:
    the_name = result.td.span.get_text().split(',')[0]
```

Comment: Good idea ! But I don't get the second part : result.td.span.get_text().split(' ,     ')[0] ? It returns me AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'. What do you think ?

Comment: The idea is to look in the `td` element, then in the included `span` element.  What that error means is that this tree wasn't found for one of the `tr` elements.  Maybe add a `print` statement in there to see if you're finding any of them.  Sorry I'm not in a place right now where I can test it, but I will be later.